# Sending a info to detailview from UICollectionView is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I think i didnt explain well in the title, heres the problem, I have a collection view that is supplying from a json, but when I go to the detail it crashes, i think the problem is in this part of the code when I send the info to the detail:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {


        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        MenuDetailViewController *menu = [segue destinationViewController];
        EntryJson *entry = [[InfoWeb sharedInstance] entryAtIndex:row];
        menu.galeriademo = entry.imagenes;
        menu.DetailModalprim = @[entry.title == nil ? @"" : entry.title,
                                 entry.date == nil ? @"" : entry.date,
                                 entry.desc == nil ? @"" : entry.desc,
                                 entry.mainimage == nil ? @"" : entry.mainimage,
                                 entry.seccion == nil ? @"" : entry.seccion];


    }

}
```

In a tableview the IndexPath would be like: NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexpathforselectedRow];

I had a tableview working like this and it was fine but when I change to a collection view i had this problem. The crash log is the next:

```
2014-03-07 12:41:00.696 CMT[28640:70b] -[__NSArrayI row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc34d180
2014-03-07 12:41:00.698 CMT[28640:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc34d180'
```

So I need your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns an NSarray, not an NSIndexPath

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
```

should be

```
NSArray *myIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [myIndexPahts objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Of course, thank you, Im a starter so hope you understand me :)